# Classification Tree for a table

Tags: r, tree, classification, decision-tree

### Problem Description

I have a simple table with 2 factors and 3 rows (Table 1). Note that in this table there are three unique patterns for Factor1 and Factor2, which are F1=0&F2=1, F1=1&F2=0 and F1=1&F2=1. The 2 factors determines the target variable. My aim is to obtain the list of unique patterns using a tree.

My [link to tables and figures](http://xeyonesoft.net/StatDiagram/Stat-Question1.gif) is essential to describe this problem.

I represent the table in a tree. I call this tree a classification tree (Figure 1). The depth of the tree is 2. The depth should be equal to the number of factors. For example, The node N4 in Figure 1 represents the unique pattern F1=1&F2=1. The way to interpret the pattern is to traverse the tree from the top node N1 to N4.
Six nodes are generated to represent the tree. I only know how to create the tree (Figure 1) using powerpoint.

### Question

How can I create this tree programmatically? Is there any library/algorithm that can draw this? Any program will do, not necessarily R. Please provide a sample code like my R code below.

### What I have tried

To solve this problem, I have attempted to use R rpart to generate a decision tree (Figure 2). Only 5 nodes are generated out of the expected 6 nodes that I need. I think I understand why is this so. A decision tree is different because it only shows node that can predict the target variable. The tree I need is not to predict, but to show a breakdown of all factors. My R code is attached below.

I looked around and stumbled upon these options:

- Use a completely unpruned decision tree. But my decision tree is already unpruned?
- use random forest to grow more observations such that the decision tree is able to show node N6 as well.
- Find another tree construction algorithm - not decision tree.

### Background

The aim is to use decision tree to predict factors that contribute to the target variable. However, for reporting purpose, I want to show how much data has been reduced using the decision tree. For example, Figure 2 shows that 1 node has been reduced by the decision tree (no N6). For a bigger data, the reduction in nodes will be more evident.

### My R code:

```
library(rpart.plot)  
F1<-c(0,1,1)
F2<-c(1,0,1)
TargetVar<-c(1,1,0)
mydata2 <- data.frame(F1, F2, TargetVar)
cart = rpart(TargetVar~., data = mydata2)
fit2 <- rpart(TargetVar~., method="class", data=mydata2, control=rpart.control(minsplit=1, cp=0.001))
rpart.plot(fit2, type = 4, extra =2)
```

Comment: If you want to show a specific hierarchy variables and splits, outside the context of a model, you could draw a diagram that has the specific features you want. Two tutorials that might be helpful are [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/Diagram/diagram.pdf) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diagram/vignettes/diagram.pdf). This is probably less automated than you were hoping for, but it's an option if no one steps in with a better solution.

Comment: why the mathematica tag?